# How to get specific single with status live

Tags: templating, entries, singles, status

How can I get a specific single (careers) with status live in twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% set careers = craft.entries.section('careers') %}

{% if not careers|length %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```